# Should I use CSS 2.1 features only or is it OK to use CSS 3 features nowadays?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Excuse me if I'm asking a stupid question because I have never worked on the web front-end development before.

My project is a web app that's implemented with React.js. On one view, we want to display a table of text messages and make the text wrap when the browser window is resized. To do this, I defined the following CSS class and applied it to the `<td>`:

```
.td-content {
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

When I validated my CSS definition using the [W3C CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), the validator said:

> Property `word-break` doesn't exist in `CSS level 2.1` but exists in `[css3]` : `break-all`

When I changed the validator's profile to `CSS 3`, everything was good.

I noticed the [CSS 2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) is in the "Recommendation" status, while the [CSS Text Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/) is still a "Working Draft" which, according to [this document](https://www.w3.org/Style/2011/CSS-process.en.html), seems to be at the very early stage of the spec, which gives me the impression that CSS 3 is still quite unstable and I should stick with CSS 2.1.

So **my questions** are:

- How important is it to use CSS 2.1 features only in the web development nowadays? In other words, is it safe to use CSS features that only exist in Level 3?
- Can I specify the CSS level used in my web app? I can't find anywhere in my React.js files to specify the level.

Comment: `word-break` is widely supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=word-break. Don't worry about it. Even if you could specify the level, what's the point? Browsers will simply ignore unsupported CSS properties. Edit: re-reading my comment, this Q should probably be closed as OT / opinion-based

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you! I will just use that!

Comment: @ChrisG In terms of specifying the CSS level: in fact, I don't know if it is a common practice to specify the level somewhere explicitly. I thought the earlier standard is usually well supported on all the mainstream browsers, while the new standard may not. So I think it may be a good idea to use the features that work on all the browsers.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to specify the CSS level. Again, what's the point anyway? Is the browser supposed to not display the page if the level is too high? Certainly not. Backwards compatibility is always a good idea, but there's no CSS2 equivalent to `word-break`. New versions simply add properties or values. Ideally your pages work even without them, but you can't guarantee that, so at some point you'll simply have to accept the fact that a small percentage of people who for some reason use an outdated browser have a suboptimal experience. I don't really care about them anyway.